# How to fill path with only effect without color inside it or low opacity color in JavaFx?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx-8

I'm currently using Canvas in JavaFx8.

Let's say I just draw some path inside GraphicContex, and fill it with green ,stroke it with yellow while apply yellow inner shadow effect on it. Here is my current code

```
public void draw(GraphicsContext gc) {
    drawsomePath(gc);
    gc.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 1d));
    InnerShadow innerglow = new InnerShadow(20.0d, Color.rgb(255, 255, 0, 1.0d));
    innerglow.setChoke(0.5);
    gc.setEffect(innerglow);
    gc.fill();
    gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0, 1.0d));
    gc.setLineWidth(3);
    gc.stroke();

    gc.setLineWidth(1);
    gc.setEffect(null);
}
```

With this code I'm able to achieve this:

[image: What I doesn't want]

which is not what I want, here is what I want:

[image: what I want][image: what I want2]

As you can see what I want is to have path filled with color that are semi-transparent green or transparent.

I've try adjust the alpha value or fill Color.TRANSPARENT with effect apply... These doesn't work. It looks like JavaFx effect care about alpha value of filled color.

How do I get this to work?

Ps. photos are photoshoped to make it easy to understand.

Comment: One way I can think of is to capture all the pixel inside path turn them to image and apply effect to it which seems too complicated.